# How to Rewrite a url in a subdirectory and parameters?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Here is the page I'm working with:**

> www.domain.com/clothing/mens/brand.html?brand=DOPE

**I would like to change it to:**

> www.domain.com/clothing/mens/DOPE

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^mens/brand/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```

*but that produces the undesired effect:*

> www.domain.com/clothing/mens/brand/DOPE

when I remove "brand":

```
RewriteRule  ^mens/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```

I don't get an error but a blank page.
***What am I doing wrong?*** I have tried everything and nothing seems to work :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^clothing/mens/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /clothing/mens/brand.html?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```

The page you are working with is brand.html or brand.php?

Comment: I'm working with brand.php but I have a rewrite previously that changes .php to .html does that change how it processes? By the way, I tried what you have posted, but it still doesn't work, the error is: _The requested URL /clothing/mens/DOPE was not found on this server._

Comment: If you only change brand.php to brand.html in previous RewriteRule, you can use this:

RewriteRule  ^clothing/mens/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /clothing/mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]

for better performance.

Comment: I tried it with brand.php and brand.html; both output the same result.

Comment: Can you please help me? I'm stuck.

Comment: Try this:
RewriteRule  ^clothing/mens/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /clothing/mens/brand.html?brand=$1 [NC,R]

Do you see the link www.domain.com/clothing/mens/DOPE redirects?

Comment: It does redirect, but its very strange in how it does so, If you notice below, I am almost close by using: `RewriteRule ^mens/-([\da-z]+) mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]`,however I do not know how to remove the "-" character...

Comment: I just wonder why you remove "clothing" out of your rewriterule. If so you can use RewriteBase /clothing/

Comment: I apologize I forgot to mention that I did use `RewriteBase /clothing/ the line before

Comment: I don't know if this helps:

RewriteBase /clothing/
RewriteRule  ^mens\/([\da-z]+)\/? mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Let do a little recap. You want to have this redirection:

```
clothing/mens/DOPE   ->   clothing/mens/brand.html?brand=DOPE
```

But the rule you're using (the first mentioned in your question) will do this:

```
mens/brand/DOPE      ->   clothing/mens/brand.html?brand=DOPE
```

I think you should use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^clothing/mens/([\da-z]+) mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note that you can simply use `[\da-z]` (or `[0-9a-z]`) instead of `[0-9a-zA-z]`, as you're using the No Case `[NC]` flag.

Comment: It seems like that doesn't work either as it returns, " The requested URL clothing/mens/DOPE was not found on this server."

Comment: However,  I did notice that when I edit it to this `RewriteRule  ^mens/-([\da-z]+) mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [NC,L]` 
I get closer to the desired result with the exception that the it adds a "-" in front of DOPE so it outputs , "clothing/mens/-DOPE"

Comment: I don't know how to get rid of the "-", is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all that have tried to help, but here is what worked for anyone else looking for an answer.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mens/([^/]+)$ mens/brand.php?brand=$1 [L]
```